# Can a hi-rep user see or review posts of his that were flagged?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, comment-flags

I think the title speaks for itself. If I saw a comment from a hi-rep (10K+) user that has access to all the moderator tools, and that comment was *not constructive* to the point of being on the verge of being *rude* if not purely *condescending*, and if I flagged that comment as such... would that hi-rep user be able to:

1. See the flag in some flag queue
2. Dismiss the flag or somehow *mootinize* it?

Seeing [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194623/seeing-own-posts-that-have-been-flagged-in-the-10k-tools) pop up in the "Similar Questions" while typing, and reading it, isn't very encouraging. Sorry if this is [likely] a duplicate, couldn't find it - [the answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134469/can-we-see-the-moderators-response-to-a-flagged-comment) has the closest clue I could find, but "*I'm pretty sure that 10k users don't see flags on their own posts*" isn't much of a definitive answer.

Comment: Well, only moderators can even see comment flags. 10k users only see NAA, VLQ, and I believe a select set of automatically generated Community flags.

Comment: @animuson Yep, we can see Excessively long, Duplicate answer, and Rollback war. (I believe that's all; I may have forgotten a few)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only moderators with diamonds can see comment flags of any kind. That said, if the user deletes their offending comment then the flag would be dismissed as well, but that's not really a problem.

Comment: That's good to know, but (not that I think it would actually happen, mods get elected and it would be in contradiction with the very nature of their status) what if a diamond moderator started being rude/condescending, would the system allow them to review their own flagged post?

Comment: @retailcoder: Technically yes, but we're *totally* responsible and let other mods review them instead.